# Javascript Date from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, object

I have an array of dates which I am looping through to get each element. the elements are not date objects but strings (I think).

If I display each of the elements to the console I get:
2015,09,19
2015,09,21

I'm trying to turn them into normal dates but I keep getting invalid date. If I statically try

```
var temp = new Date(2015,09,21);
```

it works fine but if I do

```
var temp = new Date(datax[i]);
```

I get invalid date

full loop below

```
            for (var i = 0; i < datax.length; i++) {
            var temp = new Date(datax[i]); // fails says invalid date
            //var temp = new Date(2015,09,21); //works fine but is statically assigned (want to get it from array)
            console.log(temp);
        }
```

thanks for any help

Comment: What is in the array?

Comment: two elements... one with 2015,09,19 and the next with 2015,09,21

Comment: new Date(2015,09,21) is 3 arguments, new Date(datax[i]) is only one so it's clearly not the same. update your code with the ouput of datax[i], doing console.log(datax[i]);

Comment: the output is already in my post

Comment: @user2229747 You might want to elaborate more on what `2015,09,19` is. Is that an array of numbers? Is that a string? What's that?

Comment: like Secular kid basically said: new Date(datex[i][0], datex[i][1], datex[i][2])

Comment: @chriskelly That's terrible. Don't do that. Use `.apply` instead.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 : Why is that terrible? Apply is just syntactic sugar for the same thing.

Comment: @chriskelly Touche, it's just syntactic sugar. I just like my code to be compact and easy to read.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 : that's ok :) I actually prefer apply but we still don't know if its a string or array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If content of array is a string like "2015,19,09" for example, go with

```
new Date(datax[i].replace(/,/g, "-");
```

It should do it.

I guess "2015,19,09" is not a valid string to be parsed by the date object, but "2015-19-09" will.

Or if you want the same pattern as what you tried manually, first parse the string and make it an array.

```
var temp = datax[i].split(",");
temp = new Date(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2]);
```

If the content of the array is itself an array, go for

```
new Date(datax[i][0], datax[i][1], datax[i][2]);
```

Comment: thank you soooo much. I hate dates but I wasn't aware that a date took three inputs and presumed that the , was already separating them! thank you again